# How to change the limitrequestfieldsize in Apache 2.4.2

Tags: apache, configuration

I'm working with Apache 2.4.2 and I need to change the LimitRequestFieldSize. supposedly (according to some Google researchs) that can be done in the httpd.conf file but I cant find that LimitRequestFieldSize neither the httpd.conf or any file within the Apache. Have any idea how I can do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the end I solved simply adding LimitRequestFieldSize 500000 to the file httpd-default.conf

Comment: The default for Apache 2.4.2 is 8192 bytes. You increased the value by 61 times the default.  Limits exist to protect systems. A better approach is to incrementally increase a setting until the error goes away. Generally, double the value. If it works try the half way point between initial value and doubled value.  8192 -> 16384 -> (8192/2 + 8192 = 12288).   Google the Slow Loris attack. Then read about Slow Loris -- cute but, deadly.

Comment: I can choke your server with a simple command, then your server will be flood with header data...should not increase tooo much, should be double default.

Answer (score 13):

What you just did is open the door to a DoS attack.

Take a look at the LimitRequestFieldSize directive in [the Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestfieldsize):

Quoting from that source:

> This directive specifies the number of bytes that will be allowed in
>   an HTTP request header.
>
> The LimitRequestFieldSize directive allows the server administrator to
>   set the limit on the allowed size of an HTTP request header field. A
>   server needs this value to be large enough to hold any one header
>   field from a normal client request. The size of a normal request
>   header field will vary greatly among different client implementations,
>   often depending upon the extent to which a user has configured their
>   browser to support detailed content negotiation. SPNEGO authentication
>   headers can be up to 12392 bytes.
>
> This directive gives the server administrator greater control over
>   abnormal client request behavior, which may be useful for avoiding
>   some forms of denial-of-service attacks.

The documentation also specifies that the context of that directive is server config (which means server-wide) and virtual host (you can apply this directive on a per-vhost basis).

In addition, you do not mention what your OS is. In case it's Linux (which I'm more familiar with):

- The configuration file, httpd.conf, is found in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (RHEL, CentOS, Fedora, Scientific Linux).
- In Debian, and derivatives like Ubuntu (I don't think that is the case here, but I am mentioning it anyway just for the record), the configuration file is apache2.conf and can be found in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.

Hope it helps.

And last but not least, you may want to check out the [Unix and Linux Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) here in StackExchange for questions like this (assuming Linux or other *Nix OS). You may have better luck at getting an answer.

Comment: Be aware that this has to be defined *before* loading any Virtual Host

Comment: @binco oh my god, you finally cracked the code for me, THANK YOU.  I've always put new config on the bottom, and it wasn't until I moved it to the top that it finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be solved by updating the directive LimitRequestFieldSize either in the apache httpd.conf or in the virtual hosts.

#### How to add the prop in the virtual host

```
<VirtualHost 10.10.50.50:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    
    LimitRequestFieldSize 16384
    
    RewriteEngine On
    ...
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

### How to add in the httpd.conf which is inside , apache2/conf/httpd.conf

LimitRequestFieldSize 16384

But even after doing this i am still getting bad request error.