# Error 413 with POSTing large string

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, http-status-code-413

I'm trying to upload images using the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API, and writing the data URL from the `FileReader.readAsDataURL()` method to a file using PHP on the server side.

The method works with smaller images (not sure exactly how small, but < 1MB is probably fairly acurate). However, when uploading larger images, I get a 413 Request Entity Too Large error. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836537/apache-413-request-entity-too-large-with-large-string) and tried both of the solutions, however the first did nothing and the second gave a 500 error. When I checked the error log it said:

```
 /home/username/public_html/.htaccess: LimitRequestFieldsize not allowed here
```

Why isn't this working?

**php.ini**

```
file_uploads = On
post_max_size = 50M
upload_max_filesize = 50M
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On 

# LimitRequestFieldSize 2097152

SSLRenegBufferSize 1000000
```

**JS**

```
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {

      $.ajax({
        url: "?action=saveImg",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          image: e.target.result,
          id: id
        },
        success: function(data){
          $.dialog(data.message, data.title);
        }
      });
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++){
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
    }
  }
}

$("#file").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});
```

**PHP**

```
$id = $_POST["id"];

$filetype = str_replace('data:', '', explode(";", $_POST["image"])[0]);

$data = $_POST["image"];

list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);

$rand = random_str(6);

$ext = explode("/", $filetype)[1];

if(!is_dir("../../images/product/{$id}/")){
  mkdir("../../images/product/{$id}/");
}

$fh = fopen("../../images/product/{$id}/{$rand}.{$ext}", "w+");
fwrite($fh, $data);
fclose($fh);

$return = ["message" => "ID is $id. Saved image as /images/product/{$id}/{$rand}.{$ext}.", "title" => "Saved Image", "image" => "/images/product/{$id}/{$rand}.{$ext}"];
echo json_encode($return);

die();
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Are you sure you are reading the right error line?

Comment: Pretty sure. What else could it be?

Comment: I wonder if `LimitRequestFieldsize` directive has anything to do with *413 Request Entity Too Large* error.

Comment: ... and obviously it is logged since you used directive directly inside .htaccess file which you shouldn't.

Comment: The answer I saw seemed to think that `LimitRequestFieldsize` had something to do, and where else should I have used the directive? I'm on a godaddy shared server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the limitrequestfieldsize in Apache 2.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273399/how-to-change-the-limitrequestfieldsize-in-apache-2-4-2)

Comment: Are you sure your php.ini file got read?

Comment: Fairly sure. I checked on the [godaddy help site](https://www.godaddy.com/help/phpiniuserini-changes-not-taking-effect-5647), and they said that starting a new session would read the php.ini file.

Comment: Well, don't post it as a base64 url... it's ~3x larger! use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)!

Answer (score -1):

## This is an apache config issue

There are many potential causes of this issue, aside from `LimitRequestFieldsize`.

#### [LimitRequestFieldsize](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitrequestfieldsize)

First, LimitRequestFieldsize *usually* must be set in a `.conf` file, rather than `.htaccess`. Additionally, there are significant security implications to increasing the limit. (slow loris attack for one)

#### [SecRequestBodyLimit](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#SecRequestBodyLimit) (if you're using mod_security)

Also must be set in a `.conf` file. Also has security implications.

```
SecRequestBodyLimit 10485760
```

## Your question belongs on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com)